# Scripts shell recording playback

Tags: linux, bash, script, cat

I hope this makes sense.  I use 'scripts' to make copies of my ssh sessions for various reasons.

When I access the logs via less, etc, I see this:

```
Script started on Mon 12 Sep 2011 08:59:14 AM CDT

ESC]0;root@:~^G[root@ESC[1;31m ESC[0;0m~]# 
ESC]0;root@:~^G[root@ESC[1;31m ESC[0;0m~]# logout
ESC[HESC[2JConnection to closed.^M
Script started on Mon 12 Sep 2011 09:00:32 AM CDT
Last login: Sat Sep 10 18:13:00 2011 from ^M
ESC]0;root@:~^G[root@ESC[1;31m ESC[0;0m~]# 
ESC]0;     3.03, 2.32, 2.20^G
test.log (END)
```

When I cat it, I see this:

```
Perk ~ # cat test.log 
Script started on Mon 12 Sep 2011 08:59:14 AM CDT

[root@ ~]# 
[root@ ~]# logout

Connection to closed.
Script started on Mon 12 Sep 2011 09:00:32 AM CDT
Last login: Sat Sep 10 18:13:00 2011 from 
[root@ ~]# [/code]
```

If I try and pipe this to a file, it returns to look like the less output.

When I edit it in vi, this is what i see:

```
Script started on Mon 12 Sep 2011 08:59:14 AM CDT
^M
^[]0;root@:~^G[root@^[[1;31m ^[[0;0m~]# ^M
^[]0;root@:~^G[root@^[[1;31m ^[[0;0m~]# logout^M
^[[H^[[2JConnection to closed.^M^M
Script started on Mon 12 Sep 2011 09:00:32 AM CDT
Last login: Sat Sep 10 18:13:00 2011 from ^M^M
^[]0;root@:~^G[root@^[[1;31m ^[[0;0m~]# ^M
^[]0;     3.03, 2.32, 2.20^G^M
```

Does anyone know how I can get this `cat` output into a file for easy viewing?

Comment: It works properly with `cat` because your terminal emulator interprets these caracters as colors for the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of regular [less](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less), try:

```
less -R
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [script](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_script.htm)

```
script -t scriptfile > timingsfile
```

So you can

```
replay scriptfile
```

The timing are optional. In fact you could run `replay |`[`ansifilter`](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/ansifilter.html) to translate into, say, HTML etc.

to have the exact script replayed in real-time. I think this is much more apt as clearly you are trying to log interactive sessions <sub>(most Unix tools are aware of when they are not connected to a tty (batch mode, piped stdin/out), and already prevent emitting terminal codes in such cases)</sub>

---

There is also [termrec](http://www.enel.ucalgary.ca/People/Norman/encm339fall2001/termrec/) which is able to control the playback speed. Nice for creating specific screenshots e.g.

Comment: Your `script ... > timingsfile` should be `script ... 2> timingsfile` to capture stderr (the timing data output) in timingsfile, rather than stdout. 
 Also, note that JPerkSter already is using `script`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command `colcrt` which strips terminal formatting codes.